# Android open gl 2D game specifying minimum screen resolution

Tags: android

I've nearly finished porting a 2D game to Android and am using libgdx/Open GL, my target screen resolution is 800x480 (wvga, the same as the original game).  My question is, when I eventually submit this to the marketplace, how do I specify this as the required screen resolution?

I've seen the  section in the AndroidManifest.xml file can be used to specify supported sizes, can this be used to ensure only 800x480 is supported?

Comment: Well, i dont think that limit the game to just people that have WVGA screens is a good way to do this. Maybe scaling your game to fit screens is better.

Answer (score 1):

follow the this page

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html

an example usage;

```
<supports-screens
              android:smallScreens="true"
              android:normalScreens= "true"
              android:largeScreens="true"
              android:xlargeScreens="true"
              android:anyDensity="true" />
```